Использование многоточия вместе с другими знаками препинания
Перевожу игру с английского на русский и там местами встречается использование многоточий вместе с вопросительным или восклицательным знаком (либо сразу и то и то). Так вот я их переводил как есть ("...?", "...!" и "...?!"), но вчера узнал что вроде бы правильно должно быть вот так ("?..", "!.." и "?!.")
И тут возникло сразу несколько вопросов:

Неужели вот это "?!." будет понятнее чем "...?!"
Применимо ли это, если сама фраза и состоит лишь из "...?"
Можно ли оставить как было и ничего не менять, не будет ли это каким-то грубым нарушением


Эта тема на форуме рассматривалась не единожды.
• Вот главные рекомендации:

1. После вопросительного/восклицательного знака ставятся не три точки (обычный вид многоточия), а две (третья точка стоит под одним из названных знаков): Сколько жить ещё на свете?.. (Тв.); А как вы вчера играли!.. (Остр.)
2. При «встрече» многоточия с запятой последняя поглощается многоточием, которое указывает не только на пропуск слов, но и на пропуск знака препинания: Жена его... впрочем, они были совершенно довольны друг другом (Г.).


§ 154. При сочетании вопросительного и восклицательного знаков вначале ставится основной знак, указывающий на цель высказывания — вопросительный знак, а затем — восклицательный знак как показатель эмоциональной окрашенности высказывания: — Что же стоите-то?! — закричал он еще издали (Шукш.); — Еще надо?! — Елизар стукнул кулаком по столу [Шукш.).
При сочетании вопросительного или восклицательного знака с многоточием знаки эти ставятся на месте первой точки: — Ну, что они там?.. (Шукш.); — Сейчас зайдем к старику, так?.. (Шукш.); «Эх, елки зеленые!..» — горько подумал он (Шукш.).

• Примеры
Все расписавшись? Ну, теперь глядите!.. Раз... два... три!!. (А. П. Чехов. Маска).
― Я?! ― возмутился Рымарь. ― С моей кристальной честностью?!. (С. Довлатов. Чемодан).
✦ При переводе с любого языка на русский оформление прямой речи, цитат и других пунктуационных особенностей необходимо делать в соответствии с правилами русского языка.
Рекс Стаут (перевод с английского П. Гормузова):
— О!.. Какая сила, — пробормотал Вульф.
— Ясно. Еще что-нибудь?..
— Какого черта вы здесь делаете?!
— Ради бога!.. Кто тут?.. Помогите...
§ 68. Многоточие и другие знаки (Розенталь)
Сочетание знаков препинания и последовательность их расположения (Лопатин)
Вопросы о сочетании знаков ("Грамота")
Дополнение после комментария

Вот это "?!." для меня понятнее, чем "...?!".
Приведите, пожалуйста, пример.
Если оставить как было и ничего не менять...
В большой литературе (в крупном издательстве при наличии корректора) — не пройдет, будет считаться ошибкой. Исправят.
В самиздате же или при малом тираже, возможно, сойдет за авторскую пунктуацию.


Это я видел уже несколько раз и это НЕ отвечает на 3 поставленных мною вопроса. Неужели так сложно просто написать да или нет?

Приветствую вас на форуме, Crazyx! Помягче, пожалуйста, помягче. Просто "да" или "нет" написать, конечно же, не сложно. Однако все вопросы и ответы здесь читает масса пользователей, не только вы. Может, еще кто увидит? Может, еще кому пригодится?

Извиняюсь если показался слишком грубым, но действительно неприятно, когда видишь десятки одинаковых ответов, спрашиваешь прямым текстом несколько вопросов, а их как будто игнорируют
По ответам:
2. Допустим персонаж А, говорит что-то, что вводит персонажа Б в ступор и для изображения эмоции непонимания персонаж Б говорит "...?"
3. Не совсем понимаю о чем вы, как я и писал в начале вопроса, я перевожу игру и там ничего подобного нет

• В диалоге используется просто восклицательный или вопросительный знак. Тут уж дополнительные точки не нужны, потому что никакая речь не обрывается.  Такое своеобразное их употребление объясняется тем, что «значение восклицательного и вопросительного знаков настолько определенно и общепринято, что оказывается возможным с помощью этих знаков выразить удивление, сомнение, возмущение и т. п... даже без слов» (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=160) • А вдруг ваш классный перевод будет кем-то использован в своем тексте, то есть процитирован? Лучше всё же поставить общепринятые знаки.

Вот и славно, разобрались! Будут еще проблемы — спрашивайте. Только лучше с конкретными примерами. Успехов!
